# Kali-Linux update - Fatal error, no space left on device

Tags: linux, memory, kali-linux

Hey guys I have a slight issue I'm trying to resolve, I had an older version kali linux on a usb stick (32gb) with persistent memory. I did apt get && apt update to update it, it processed through most of the update until it output a fatal error that it was out of memory.  Now anytime I attempt to update the OS, or install any new application I'm getting that fatal error.

When doing dpkg --configure -a

I get this error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unable to flush /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i after padding: No space left on device
```

This is what I have for df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  9.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       3.1G  3.1G     0 100% /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1
/dev/loop0      2.8G  2.8G     0 100% /lib/live/mount/rootfs    /filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /lib/live/mount/overlay
aufs            3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G  160K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G  508K  3.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           788M   28K  788M   1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb2        79M   75M  3.7M  96% /media/root/Kali Live
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
/dev/sdb1       3.1G  3.1G     0 100% /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1
```

You see that there is no space left in /dev/sdb1.
Look if you can clean up /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1

Comment: Is there a specific command I could use to clean it up? or a way to increase the partition space?

Comment: with the command "ls" you can look for the files and "rm" removes them.